# How can I workaround this CSS anomaly?

Tags: css

I have what I think is some pretty basic css, and it behaves differently in FF4 and IE8.

The CSS in question is like this:

```
  div.showme  {
     border: 1px dotted blue;
     position: absolute;
     top :10px;
     bottom :10px;
     left: 1%;
     right: 33%;
     overflow: auto;
     padding: 0.8em 1em 0.8em 1em;
     line-height:1.75em;
  }

  div.showme a {
     padding: 0em 5px 0em 5px;
     margin: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
     color: #FF00FF;
     background-color:#E6E6FA;
     border: 1px solid grey;
     padding: 0em 4px 0em 4px; }

  div.showme a:link       { color: blue; }
  div.showme a:visited    { color: #1E90FF; }
  div.showme a:active     { color: red; }
```

The relevant HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='showme'>
  <a href='one'>one</a>
  <a href='two'>two</a>
   ...
</div>
```

The problem is, the padding is not consistently displayed, in IE8.

[image]

In Firefox, it works as I would expect.

working example:
http://jsbin.com/ogosa4

Using the above working demonstration, if you resize the window you will see the padding on the "leading" element on each line within the div, change from zero to non-zero.

How can I fix this?

Comment: +1 for awesome question that I would like to know the answer to as well.  have you tried `reset.css`?

Comment: Actually when I originally saw it, I had the yahoo css reset in the page. I removed that from the simple demo because I think it's extraneous.

Comment: IE's short-comings are usually met with `extraneous.css` :|  I would dump a girl if she used IE 6... not gonna lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `display: inline-block;` to your `div.showme a {}` the padding will be applied in IE also, but it has some impact with the line height and you may need to specify additional margin's

Comment: `inline-block` is awesom, but be carefuly with it if you need to support IE7 (or worse, IE6), in which case you may need to use browser hacks.

Comment: I know, but he asked about IE8, so i thought it's worth posting it.

Comment: Ok, that definitely made the left-hand side padding uniform, and as you suspected, the heights of the boxes are too large. I'll look into that.

Comment: adding `line-height: 1em` for the `a` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behaviour in Opera too. The padding goes to the upper line. Try `display: inline-block` and `white-space:nowrap` if you have more than one word in the link...

You can safely use `inline-block` in IE7 with inline tags.